# std::bad_alloc error in DBSCAN

Tags: r, dbscan

I am getting the error,

> std::bad_alloc error

when I try to use `DBSCAN algorithm` of `fpc package`. Data set is large( `50k spatial coordinates`). I am not getting how to resolve this .I am working in R studio.

Comment: Cannot allocate more memory.

Comment: how to solve the memory problem

Answer (score 5):

Add more memory to your computer.

`fpc` computes all **pairwise distances**. For 50k objects that requires about 10 GB of RAM.

Consider using DBSCAN in ELKI, with the cover tree and great-circle distance.

This does not require a distance matrix and is thus much faster and needs much less memory.